# Samba only works if logged in over ssh

Tags: server, windows-7, ssh, samba

I have a headless ubuntu server running samba. I have a windows 7 laptop, windows 8 desktop, a lubuntu desktop running xbmc, and a samsung note2 running android. Whenever *any* of these computers has a terminal window open running ssh to the server(mothership) samba works perfectly for everything on the network. As soon as I logout or close the terminal window, nothing can access the shared files.

Here is the samba config on mothership:

```
[global]
; General server settings
netbios name = mothership
server string = mothership
workgroup = WORKGROUP
announce version = 5.0
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_KEEPALIVE SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192

passdb backend = tdbsam
security = user
null passwords = true
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
name resolve order = lmhosts wins bcast host hosts

wins support = no

printing = CUPS
printcap name = CUPS

syslog = 1
syslog only = yes

[MyFiles]
path = /home/<my_name>/media
browseable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
```

/home and everything in it is set to 755. Does anyone know how I can get samba to work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have an encrypted home directory?

If you do then it is only decrypted when you are logged in.

Try creating a share for a directory that is not in your home directory and see if that works.